# Java libjava.so file error

Tags: java

It's been a day since I am trying to get "java" command run on a server, that has java5 jre installed. Problem is I always get

> Error: could not find libjava.so Error: could not find Java 2 Runtime Environment.

even if I run it from the installation directory, /usr/lib/java1.5/jre/bin. I can see libjava.so is in ../jre/lib/amd64 directory but not sure why wouldn't it get picked up. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Very weird error. I noticed you're using a 64-bit OS. Found this [link](http://richizo.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/solving-the-problem-error-cant-find-libjava-so/) that talks of a problem between older versions of java and 64-bit OSes. Java 1.5 was released 2004 and 64-bit processors were only introduced to mainstream computer market in 2003. Meaning this could be a likely culprit.

---

For posterity (in case the page gets deleted):

This problem refer to the installation of old JDKs  on 64bit Linux systems.
When java command is executed at shell, generally, you will receive this error message:

> Error: can't find libjava.so.

To solve this problem just edit 3 files located at JDK installation dir and be happy

- $JAVA_HOME/bin/.java_wrapper
- $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/.java_wrapper
- $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin/realpath

All these 3 files have similar code snippet as bellow:

```
case "`uname -m`" in
    i[3-6]86 | ia32 | ia64 | i?86)
        proc=i386
        ;;
    sparc*)
        proc=sparc
        ;;
    *)
        proc=unknown
        ;;
esac
```

Edit each file and  include the architecture x86_64 in the first case-statement and the problem will be fixed:

```
    i[3-6]86 | ia32 | ia64 | i?86 | x86_64)
```

Comment: I used both "locate" and "find" but din't find libjli.so file anywhere on my machine.

Comment: @Abidi I found a forum post that may be of interest to you. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your research Dunes, but I don't have any of these files even I downloaded and installed fresh copy of java 5. May be worth mentioning - I am chrooting to a directory and then doing installation.

Comment: Thanks. This answer was invaluable during my Java 1.3 setup. I needed this along with an old glibc to get Java 1.3 going. Also, thanks for posting the solution inline (the page linked to has indeed disappeared).

Comment: I have this with java 1.6 and your instruction doesn't help.

Comment: @stiv Not being able to find libjava.so could be caused by a great many number of things. You would be best off asking your own question and providing relevant information about your environment.