# Installing Oracle Java on Ubuntu

Tags: java, javac, ubuntu-11.04

I have been trying to install Oracle Java 7 on Ubuntu 11.04. I was following the [instructions given here](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux)

Once I followed all the steps ( to the letter ), I tried running

```
java -version
```

which gave the expected output. But running

```
javac -version
```

did not give the expected output. Instead I get the following error:

```
Error : Could not find libjava.so
Error : Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment
```

The environment variable PATH contains both /usr/local/java/jre/bin and /usr/local/java/jdk/bin, LD_LIBRARY_PATH points to /usr/local/lib which contains libjava.so which is currently owned by the user who I am running javac as. In addition, JAVA_HOME points to the jdk folder. Inspite of all this, javac is unable to find the libjava.so file. There are multiple solutions online but none seem to work for me. Even a direct run

```
/usr/locale/java/jdk/bin/javac -version
```

results in the same error.

Any help is hugely appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: off topic here - try http://askubuntu.com/ maybe http://superuser.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701348/java-libjava-so-file-error

Comment: Not really. That talks of a 64-bit OS while I am on a 32-bit OS. Sorry for not mentioning that.After posting, I did find a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759266/error-running-javac-in-ubuntu-11-04?rq=1 but looks like even that has not been answered :(

Comment: Judging from the fact that the instructions that you mention apparently instruct the user to `chmod +x` a *tarball*, I would not be very surpised if they do not work...

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried installing using a different link and it worked. Adding the answer for future reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Java7 on Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16263556/installing-java7-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle Java 1.7.0 from .deb packages

```
wget https://raw.github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh -7
sudo apt-get update
sudo sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-fonts oracle-java7-source 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

### Workaround for 1.7.0_51

There is an [Issue 123](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/issues/123) currently in OAB and a [pull request](https://github.com/flexiondotorg/oab-java6/pull/125)

Here is the patched vesion:

```
wget https://raw.github.com/ladios/oab-java6/master/oab-java.sh
chmod +x oab-java.sh
sudo ./oab-java.sh -7
sudo apt-get update
sudo sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-fonts oracle-java7-source 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that maybe the link had some errors. A better link to follow would be [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)

Hope that helps. The first answer on the page would be sufficient.